# How to render epub file in React Native Expo project

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, epub3

Please, help.

I have a .epub file.  How can I render it in a React native expo project. And if you know how to render an epub file with media overlay.

expo version: 43.0.2
react-native: 0.64.3

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There's no ready-made solution for rendering `ebup` file in the Expo app.

There are many services that offer API to convert EPUB TO PDF.

after converting to PDF, you can use `react-native-pdf`.This is native module linking. You will need to use an expo custom client which support adding your custom library.

Answer (score 0):

An ePub is simply xhtmlX thus in theory the contents should be renderable in any browser when unpacked.

Unfortunatly ePub have not capitalised on that simplicity, by not insisting on a sidebar of contents like in a PDF, (one very simple step)

You can extract the pages/chapters and serve them by adding your own Iframe built from the ToC as sidebar for navigation.

I don't have an example to hand on this device but chapter 2 of Homerus should look like this in the page body.

[image]

and here are the two files that either could have been easily adapted to a htmlx navbar

[image]

[image]